# is it considered good practice to pass callBacks to redux async action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to show different notification bars for success/error responses,
I pass two callBacks to an redux async action in my react component like this:

```
<Button
  onClick={e => this.props.actions.asyncAction(item, this.showSuccessBar, this.showErrorBar)}
/>
```

where asyncAction looks like this:

```
export function asyncAction(item, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(requestItem(item));
    return fetch("api.some_url/items/item")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        if (json.success) {
          dispatch(receivePostsSuccess(reddit, json));
          successCallback();
        } else {
          dispatch(receivePostsFail(reddit, json));
          errorCallback();
        }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Is this considered against the pattern? 
in other words, Should Notification Bars open according to the state change instead of callBacks?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The pattern is fine per se. If this is a notification local to the component, feel free to avoid wiring it through Redux.

That said callbacks are completely unnecessary **because you are already returning the promise.** Just wait for its completion.

```
this.props.dispatch(asyncAction(item)).then(onSuccess, onFailure);
```

However if you have many components with such notification bars, it's better to have a reducer keeping the current notification and reacting to actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked pretty good. Also really appreciate your great work on redux & devtools, etc! We loved them :) I've also got a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237712/how-to-undo-redux-async-action-multiple-steps-back-in-the-state  not sure if I'm on the right direction.

Comment: @Dan-Abramov Follow-up: if dispatch returns a promise, when does it resolve? In the above example, for instance, asyncAction returns a function (as per thunk middleware) which seems to return a chain of promises (hadn't actually seen these return before, but assuming that's kosher?); so if chaining on top of dispatch, at what point does that promise resolve?

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. I don’t understand the question. Thunk middleware will make sure thunk’s return value (a Promise) gets returned from `dispatch` itself. It resolves whenever the action creator decides and it depends on how this Promise was created. Does this help? Maybe you can create a separate question if not.

Comment: I think I get it. So, `asyncAction` is a higher-order function that when passed to `dispatch`, returns a promise. So `dispatch` resolves whenever its promises resolve (In the case of the example above, where the OP wrote `successCallback`/`errorCallback`?)

Comment: This is good. Is there any way to pass a return value to ".then(onSuccess, onFailure)"?

Comment: That's what you get in `onSuccess` as a first argument.

Comment: Why do I get `cannot read 'then' of undefined` whenever I try to use `.then()`: how would `dispatch` be undefined while it works and dispatches actions?

Comment: @ZekeDran I had the same issue - turns out the actions weren't actually returning anything at all. They need to be returning the Promise!

Comment: This is incorrect.  Passing the return value to your callback breaks the unidirectional data flow of flux/redux.  If you do this your state will exist in your reducer and your callback.  You should be accessing your state from the reducer only.

Comment: React-redux's `dispatch` prop doesn't seem to be returning a promise! Weird.

Comment: @DanAbramov in the docs https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html you say "Actions are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store". I agree. For me actions describe an event or an intent of change or mutation, and they notify many places of the architecture. Putting a sideffecty callback in an action to jump the architecture for me is not a good pattern, the callback is not describing an intent of change.

Comment: @DanAbramov what happens when we use sagas?

Answer (score 5):

This would be bi-directional data flow, which breaks the first rule of flux.

Comment: Dan Abramov Said it's fine, and that mean it's fine :D

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having separated store named smth like `NotificationStore` and build notifications infrastructure around it. You can use callbacks, but it's way to big problems in future.