# How to undo Redux Async Action? (multiple steps back in the state)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, undo-redo, redux

if I have an async action with api call, which could either be an action returns a function:

```
export function asyncAction(itemId) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestStarted());

    return sendRequest(itemId).then(
      (result) =>  dispatch(requestSuccess()),
      (error) =>  dispatch(requestFail())
    );
  };
}
```

or one returns an object and uses middleware to intercept it and do stuff:

```
export function asyncAction(itemId) {
  return {
    type: [ITEM_REQUEST, ITEM_REQUEST_SUCCESS, ITEM_REQUEST_FAILURE],
    promise: sendRequest(itemId),
    userId
  };
}

// same middleware found in https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/99
export default function promiseMiddleware() {
  return (next) => (action) => {
    const { promise, ...rest } = action;
    if (!promise) {
      return next(action);
    }

    next({ ...rest, readyState: 'request' );
    return promise.then(
      (result) => next({ ...rest, result, readyState: 'success' }),
      (error) => next({ ...rest, error, readyState: 'failure' })
    );
  };
}
```

Now my question is: How do I **rollback** to the state before the asyncAction is dispatched, which essentially means **two steps** back in the state(success/failure => request) w/ an api call to undo last api call.
For example, after delete a todo item(which is an async action), a popup snackbar shows with an **undo** option, after click it the deleted todo item will be added back to UI along with an api call to add it back to db.

I've tried [redux-undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo) but I feel it's not intended to solve problems like this.
Or I should forget about **'undo'** and just dispatch a brand new **addTodo** action when user clicks undo option?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Redux Optimist](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/redux-optimist) might be what you need.