# Set loading state before and after an action in a React class component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have function which dispatched an action. I would like to display a loader before and after the action. I know that react composing the object passed to `setState`. the question is how can I update the property in async way:

```js
handleChange(input) {
    this.setState({ load: true })
    this.props.actions.getItemsFromThirtParty(input)
    this.setState({ load: false })
}
```

Basically, it all worked great if I put this property as part of the application state (using Redux), but I really prefer to bring this property to the component-state only.

Comment: How about this.props.dispatch(getItemsFromThirtParty()).then(/* whatever */) on the component level? I mean, as an author of redux wrote here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33168143/6538824

Do you really need a redux there?

Comment: So how are you planning to re-render the component when the action completes?

Comment: Giorgi, it's exactly the point. I don't want to use redux for the "loader" state. Of course I need redux for the application state (the actual DATA). The loader belongs to the component only, and it shouldn't be a pert of the application data. I just wish to display it when i'm fetching the data, and hide it after i'm getting the response.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Wrap the rest of your code in the callback of the first `setState`:

```js
handleChange(input) {
  this.setState({
    load: true
  }, () => {
    this.props.actions.getItemsFromThirtParty(input)
    this.setState({ load: false })
  })
}
```

With this, your `load` is guaranteed to be set to `true` before `getItemsFromThirtParty` is called and the `load` is set back to `false`.

This assumes your `getItemsFromThirtParty` function is synchronous. If it isn't, turn it into a promise and then call the final `setState` within a chained `then()` method:

```js
handleChange(input) {
  this.setState({
    load: true
  }, () => {
    this.props.actions.getItemsFromThirtParty(input)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ load: false })
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: exporting a function the returns a function that accepts a dispatch, which return Promise that resolved in setState.. Worked like magic! Thanks James!

Comment: Don't forget to set load to false in a catch block, in case the Promise gets rejected.

Comment: how we can set in useState?

Answer (score 104):

you can wrap the setState in a Promise and use async/await as below

```
setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(state, resolve)
    });
}

async handleChange(input) {
    await this.setStateAsync({ load: true });
    this.props.actions.getItemsFromThirtParty(input);
    await this.setStateAsync({ load: false })
}
```

Source: [ASYNC AWAIT With REACT](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802)

Comment: I took it a step further and did `const asyncSetState = instance => newState => new Promise(resolve => instance.setState(newState, resolve));` which you can use in any component like so ... `await asyncSetState(this)({ mystuff: false });`

Comment: Or keep it _simple_ :-) You can add this to your util to reuse
`export function setStateAsync(state, that) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    that.setState(state, resolve);
  });
}`

And call `await setStateAsync(<new state>, this)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a typescript implementation of an "async-await" setState:

```
async function setStateAsync<P, S, K extends keyof S>(
  component: Component<P, S>,
  state:
    ((prevState: Readonly<S>, props: Readonly<P>) => (Pick<S, K> | S | null)) |
    Pick<S, K> |
    S |
    null
) {
  return new Promise(resolve => component.setState(state, resolve));
}
```

Comment: I get error: `Argument of type '(value: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2345)`

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers don't work for Hooks. In this case you get the following error when passing a second argument to `setState`

> Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

As the error message says, you need to use `useEffect` instead in this case (see also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914175/11603006) for more detailed information)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do...

1. Change your action to take in a `onFetchComplete` callback, along with the `input`.
2. Change your handleChange to -

   ```
   handleChange(input) {
       this.setState({ load: true }, ()=>
           this.props.actions.getItemsFromThirtParty(input,
           ()=>this.setState({ load: false }))
       );
   }
   ```

This will ensure the action processor code can invoke back your state change callback even if it's not written in a promise based fashion.

Comment: Interesting. But Actually prefer the promise fashion. thanks for advising

Comment: Yes Promise works better. In some scenarios like Reflux, its not easily possible to return results from actions, so you can't use promises there. Also, you must remember to catch them or else you risk running the spinner forever :). Having some actions return non-promise and others promise is also something that should be clearly identified, say by their names.

Comment: Catching errors- never to be missed. And couldn't agree more about the naming!

Answer (score 0):

A small update- using promises for the action creators and async/await works great, and it makes the code even cleaner, compared to the "then" chaining:

```
(async () => {
   try {
    await this.props.actions.async1(this.state.data1);
    await this.props.actions.async2(this.state.data2) 
    this.setState({ load: false );
   } catch (e) {
    this.setState({load: false, notify: "error"});
   }
})();
```

Of course it is a matter of taste.

**EDIT : Added missing bracket**

Comment: Move `this.setState({ load: false );` in `finally`if you don't need to notify error, your code will be more succinct ;).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is about class components... But in functional components I do this to synchronously set the state:

```
const handleUpdateCountry(newCountry) {
    setLoad(() => true);
    setCompanyLocation(() => newCountry);
    setLoad(() => false);
}
```

Just worked for my automatic country detection that should set the form to dirty.

Answer (score 0):

One approach not mentioned in any of the other answer is wrapping the operation in a setTimeout. This will also work if you use hooks.

Eg.:

```
handleChange(input) {
    this.setState({ load: true })
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.actions.getItemsFromThirtParty(input).finally(() => {
            this.setState({ load: false })
        });
    });
}
```