# Executing async code on update of state with react-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-hooks

I have something like:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

...

setLoading(true);
doSomething(); // <--- when here, loading is still false.
```

Setting state is still async, so what's the best way to wait for this `setLoading()` call to be finished?

The `setLoading()` doesn't seem to accept a callback like `setState()` used to.

### an example

#### class-based

```
getNextPage = () => {
    // This will scroll back to the top, and also trigger the prefetch for the next page on the way up.
    goToTop();

    if (this.state.pagesSeen.includes(this.state.page + 1)) {
      return this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1,
      });
    }

    if (this.state.prefetchedOrders) {
      const allOrders = this.state.orders.concat(this.state.prefetchedOrders);
      return this.setState({
        orders: allOrders,
        page: this.state.page + 1,
        pagesSeen: [...this.state.pagesSeen, this.state.page + 1],
        prefetchedOrders: null,
      });
    }

    this.setState(
      {
        isLoading: true,
      },
      () => {
        getOrders({
          page: this.state.page + 1,
          query: this.state.query,
          held: this.state.holdMode,
          statuses: filterMap[this.state.filterBy],
        })
          .then((o) => {
            const { orders } = o.data;
            const allOrders = this.state.orders.concat(orders);
            this.setState({
              orders: allOrders,
              isLoading: false,
              page: this.state.page + 1,
              pagesSeen: [...this.state.pagesSeen, this.state.page + 1],
              // Just in case we're in the middle of a prefetch.
              prefetchedOrders: null,
            });
          })
          .catch(e => console.error(e.message));
      },
    );
  };
```

#### convert to function-based

```
  const getNextPage = () => {
    // This will scroll back to the top, and also trigger the prefetch for the next page on the way up.
    goToTop();

    if (pagesSeen.includes(page + 1)) {
      return setPage(page + 1);
    }

    if (prefetchedOrders) {
      const allOrders = orders.concat(prefetchedOrders);
      setOrders(allOrders);
      setPage(page + 1);
      setPagesSeen([...pagesSeen, page + 1]);
      setPrefetchedOrders(null);
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    getOrders({
      page: page + 1,
      query: localQuery,
      held: localHoldMode,
      statuses: filterMap[filterBy],
    })
      .then((o) => {
        const { orders: fetchedOrders } = o.data;
        const allOrders = orders.concat(fetchedOrders);

        setOrders(allOrders);
        setPage(page + 1);
        setPagesSeen([...pagesSeen, page + 1]);
        setPrefetchedOrders(null);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(e.message));
  };
```

In the above, we want to run each setWhatever call sequentially. Does this mean we need to set up many different useEffect hooks to replicate this behavior?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

`useState` setter doesn't provide a callback after state update is done like setState does in React class components. In order to replicate the same behaviour, you can make use of the a similar pattern like `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method in React class components with `useEffect` using Hooks

`useEffect` hooks takes the second parameter as an array of values which React needs to monitor for change after the render cycle is complete.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

...

useEffect(() => {
    doSomething(); // This is be executed when `loading` state changes
}, [loading])
setLoading(true);
```

**EDIT**

Unlike `setState`, the updater for `useState` hook doesn't have a callback, but you can always use a `useEffect` to replicate the above behaviour. However you need to determine the loading change

The functional approach to your code would look like

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

---

```
const prevLoading = usePrevious(isLoading);

useEffect(() => {
   if (!prevLoading && isLoading) {
       getOrders({
          page: page + 1,
          query: localQuery,
          held: localHoldMode,
          statuses: filterMap[filterBy],
      })
      .then((o) => {
        const { orders: fetchedOrders } = o.data;
        const allOrders = orders.concat(fetchedOrders);

        setOrders(allOrders);
        setPage(page + 1);
        setPagesSeen([...pagesSeen, page + 1]);
        setPrefetchedOrders(null);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(e.message));
   }
}, [isLoading, preFetchedOrders, orders, page, pagesSeen]);

const getNextPage = () => {
    // This will scroll back to the top, and also trigger the prefetch for the next page on the way up.
    goToTop();

    if (pagesSeen.includes(page + 1)) {
      return setPage(page + 1);
    }

    if (prefetchedOrders) {
      const allOrders = orders.concat(prefetchedOrders);
      setOrders(allOrders);
      setPage(page + 1);
      setPagesSeen([...pagesSeen, page + 1]);
      setPrefetchedOrders(null);
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);
  };
```

Comment: BTW, you can use multiple `useEffect` declarations, each one bound to the property you're interested in.

Answer (score 33):

Wait until your component re-render.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
        doSomething();
    }
}, [loading]);

setLoading(true);
```

You can improve clarity with something like:

```
function doSomething() {
  // your side effects
  // return () => {  }
}

function useEffectIf(condition, fn) {
  useEffect(() => condition && fn(), [condition])
}

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffectIf(loading, doSomething)

  return (
    <>
      <div>{loading}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setLoading(true)}>Click Me</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so I need to add a `useEffect()` to monitor each piece of state to react to it?

Comment: @Colin you can think of useEffect as componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate depending on the last arg passed to the callback in the example above [loading]

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this is a good answer; can you explain better what `doSomething` really do, and what's your use case?

Comment: I think this makes sense for now. This is a contrived example, but `doSomething()` fetches from API, and needs to know the _actual_ current state, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Colin Good explanation with examples of the hooks API https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-the-usestate-react-hook

Comment: then yeah, `useEffect` is the way to go

Comment: why not calling setLoading in the effect, if `doSomething` fetches from Api the right way could be like this : `useEffect(() => { setLoading(true); doSomething().finally(() => setLoading(false))}, [])`. Note the `[]` is used to executes the effect only ones like `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 7):

Created a custom `useState` hook which works similar to the normal `useState` hook except that the state updater function for this custom hook takes a callback that will be executed after the state is updated and component rerendered.

**Typescript Solution**

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

type OnUpdateCallback<T> = (s: T) => void;
type SetStateUpdaterCallback<T> = (s: T) => T;
type SetStateAction<T> = (newState: T | SetStateUpdaterCallback<T>, callback?: OnUpdateCallback<T>) => void;

export function useCustomState<T>(init: T): [T, SetStateAction<T>];
export function useCustomState<T = undefined>(init?: T): [T | undefined, SetStateAction<T | undefined>];
export function useCustomState<T>(init: T): [T, SetStateAction<T>] {
    const [state, setState] = useState<T>(init);
    const cbRef = useRef<OnUpdateCallback<T>>();

    const setCustomState: SetStateAction<T> = (newState, callback?): void => {
        cbRef.current = callback;
        setState(newState);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cbRef.current) {
            cbRef.current(state);
        }
        cbRef.current = undefined;
    }, [state]);

    return [state, setCustomState];
}
```

**Javascript solution**

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export function useCustomState(init) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(init);
    const cbRef = useRef();

    const setCustomState = (newState, callback) => {
        cbRef.current = callback;
        setState(newState);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cbRef.current) {
            cbRef.current(state);
        }
        cbRef.current = undefined;
    }, [state]);

    return [state, setCustomState];
}
```

**Usage**

```js
const [state, setState] = useCustomState(myInitialValue);
...
setState(myNewValueOrStateUpdaterCallback, () => {
   // Function called after state update and component rerender
})
```

Comment: callback still called after state changed to me

Answer (score 4):

you can create a async state hooks

```
const useAsyncState = initialState => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const asyncSetState = value => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setState(value);
      setState((current) => {
        resolve(current);
        return current;
      });
    });
  };

  return [state, asyncSetState];
};
```

then

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useAsyncState(false)

const submit = async () => {
  await setLoading(true)
  dosomething() 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pass a function to the setter instead of value!

instead of giving a new value to the setter directly, pass it an arrow function that takes the current state value and returns the new value.

it will force it to chain the state updates and after it's done with all of them, it will rerender the component.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const incrementCount = () => {
    setCounter( (counter) => { return counter + 1 } )
}
```

now every time incrementCount is called, it will increase the count by one and it will no longer be stuck at 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for this.

You could possibly use a React Ref to store the state of the state variable. Then update the state variable with the react ref. This will render a page refresh, and then use the React Ref in the async function.

```
const stateRef = React.useRef().current
const [state,setState] = useState(stateRef);

async function some() {
  stateRef = { some: 'value' }
  setState(stateRef) // Triggers re-render
  
  await some2();
}

async function some2() {
  await someHTTPFunctionCall(stateRef.some)
  stateRef = null;
  setState(stateRef) // Triggers re-render
}
```