# React hooks updating multiple state variables

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just found this function in code and not sure if it can actually work, because it tries to update two state variables sequentially

`changeIsOpen` and `changeInputValue` are state setters, it looks wrong for me

```
  const toggleOpen = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
  ): void => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const newOpenState: boolean = !isOpen
    changeIsOpen(newOpenState)

    const curItem: SelectSuggestV2Item | undefined = items.find(
      (item: SelectSuggestV2Item) => item.id === selectedId
    )

    // If closed and a search was in progress, restore the last selected value
    if (!newOpenState && curItem != null && curItem.label !== inputValue) {
      changeInputValue(curItem.label)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes this works fine.  Since different states are set, both will be applied. Since set setting of state is async.

Comment: Seems good to me, have you tried the code to see if its working or not?

Comment: You're right; the state setters are asynchronous, so setting `newOpenState` and then checking it soon after could be a race condition. Here's a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914175/2112512

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing async code on update of state with react-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898810/executing-async-code-on-update-of-state-with-react-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Since the snippet is not reading the `isOpen` state value after changing it, but instead is relying on its local `newOpenState` value, it should be working as intended.

If you have more complex code where you are reading / writing to / from multiple state values, you might want to consider using the `React.useReducer` hook instead.

Also multiple `set` calls in the same tick, should be properly batched by React and wont cause multiple rerenders.