# react hook useState can not store json or string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title say, the react hook useState seemed can not store my string

here is my code

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://api.localhost/user/shoppingcart", {
            headers: {
                Authorization: cookies.Authorization
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    setData(result);
                    console.log(data);
                });
    }, []);
```

the first "console.log", I can get the correct string.

```
[{"shoes":1}, {"shirt":2}]
```

but the second "console.log", I get a null string.

```
null
```

or maybe my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing async code on update of state with react-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898810/executing-async-code-on-update-of-state-with-react-hooks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setState` is `async`. So you cannot get the data right after setting the state.

**You will always get previous state if you try to `console.log` state after setting state.**

If you want to get new data, then you should have dedicated `useEffect` hook with dependency array,

```
useEffect( () => {
   console.log(data)
},
[data] //This is dependency and it will run only when data is changed
)
```

Comment: Also, event if setData was synchronous, data would still have null, because of the line `const [data, setData] = useState(null);` will not be executed until the next render.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question is misleading. I mean, it doesn't matter it is json string or not. The solution is as simple as moving the  `console.log(data);` out of the useEffect block and right after `return`(if before `return` won't be able to response). And that might be what the original poster wanted.