# How to copy array to functional state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to clone array to functional state using following code. But after setting state to new array i am still getting null array

```
const [tarFileList, setTarFileList] = React.useState([]); 

const updateTarFileList=(res)=>{
    let list=[];
    res.forEach(element => {
        list.push(element);
    });
    setTarFileList(list);
}
```

Comment: this seems to be fine, did you check the state in the dev tools ?

Comment: can you share the complete code? Because this looks fine, maybe the problem is from where you are calling this function and where you are using the updated state.

Comment: i used console.log to print the updated state but i am getting null array

Comment: @DivyanshGupta - state is updated asynchronously so you should instead log the `list` to ensure that it's not empty.

Comment: Can you tell us what a `nu` is? I don't see you using `tarFileList` anywhere so how do you know it's the same? My guess is that you are trying to access a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). React hooks are not magic and normal closure scope still applies.

Comment: Are you sure there's something inside `res` argument. Can you log `res` in the console and let us know

Comment: @Ramesh I did check the list its not empty.

Comment: @TheAlpha93 I checked res and list values. It is not empty

Comment: @DivyanshGupta - Okay, then your state is being properly updated. Try to log it in `useEffect` hook. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62410116/9765167)

Comment: @DivyanshGupta  `i am still getting null array` That is impossible because you initialise it with an empty array and set it to list in `updateTarFileList`, it is never null.

Comment: The problem is solved. The state is already being updated. I was checking the value using console.log which was wrong idea. The correct method is useEffect. Thanks @Ramesh, thanks all