# React.js Async await setState(), is this the right way to do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Without async &/or with prevState, I could not console.log the needed state of page right after setting a new state of page.

Since I've been doing some backend stuff I started learning how async works.
So I figured maybe I can use await before this.setState to get the right state for the if statement that has to come right after setting the state.

```js
changePage = async (newPage) => {
  if(this.state.page !== newPage){
    await this.setState({ page: newPage});
    console.log(this.state.page);
    if(this.state.page === ''){

    }else if(this.state.page === ''){

    }
  }
}
```

But I've never really seen this before nor ever used it in this way, so I am wondering is there a better way to do this?

Comment: **`setState` doesn't return a Promise**. So anytime it works, it's just a race-condition.

Comment: [One way to _promisify_ `setState`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744345/1218980)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a class component, `setState` takes a callback that runs after the state update. So you don't really need to use `async` or `await` and can just do:

```js
this.setState({ page: newPage}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.page);
  if(this.state.page === ''){

  }else if(this.state.page === ''){

  }
});
```