# React redux: having direct callbacks into presentation elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Do folks always have http requests come down through the global store to the container component and then to the presentation component, or is it sometimes warranted to have the presentation component provide a callback to receive the data directly when the fetch returns?

Update:
Found this SO thread with differing opinions regarding callbacks in actions:
[is it considered good practice to pass callBacks to redux async action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138045/is-it-considered-good-practice-to-pass-callbacks-to-redux-async-action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in that answer, if you already have a promise, just add a `then` or `catch` in order to run your code for both scenarios.

```
this.props.saveAction(data)
  .then(this.onSaveSuccess)
  .catch(this.onSaveFail);
```

Comment: It sounds like the general rule is that in isolated instances this is ok, but if it becomes something more broad in scope, then ideally one should work through the global store and reducers.