# Closing form modal after submit success

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-saga, formik

I am using `Formik`, `Material-ui`, `Redux`, and `Redux-saga`
I have a form inside material-ui `<Dialogue/>`

On submit of form I trigger a submit request action which then is captured by the saga.
The saga makes the api call and calls the success action.

The modals status `isOpen` is inside the component state

I need to hide the modal after the form submission succeeds.

How do I handle this?

Note: I am using React `Hooks`.

Comment: in your case, you should have inside reducer in the initialState a key like modalIsOpen:false then you open and close by calling dispatcher.

Answer (score 7):

I personally prefer to just pass a callback to the action. So your action creator becomes:

```
function confirmDelete(itemId, onSuccess) {
  return { type: ..., itemId, onSuccess)
}
```

And in your saga you basically `call(action.onSuccess)` after your have done what you need successfully.

This pattern is not a best practice in general but it is Ok for closing a modal I think. Check this SO question for a discussion around this pattern: [is it considered good practice to pass callBacks to redux async action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138045/is-it-considered-good-practice-to-pass-callbacks-to-redux-async-action)

Answer (score 1):

then probably you need to call an action after the saga call success the action must set the value in reducer say like 
`isModalClose:true` in the form have a useEffect function like

```
    `useEffect(()=>{ if(props.someReducer.isModalClode) closeModalfn() },
[props.someReducer.isModalClose])`
```