# Then() is not working after the dispatched action in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux-thunk

I have the following `Login` function:

```
export function Login(username, password) {
   return dispatch => {
    dispatch(loginBegin());

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'api/User/Login',
        data: { username, password },
    }).then(response => {

        if (response.data !== null) {
            console.log('success: Login is successful');

            dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));

        } 
    }).catch(error => { dispatch(loginFailure(error.response.data.message)) });
  }
}
```

I call this function as follows in the Login component:

```
function FormSubmitHandle(values) {
    setFormSubmitted(true);

    props.login(values.username, values.password)
        .then((login_succeeded) => {
            console.log('YESSSS');
            console.log(login_succeeded);
        });
}
```

However, `.then()` part is not working. It does not print out anything.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Your Login is a function. It's not a api call? Then how can you use .then() for a function?

Comment: @xtr `response.data` is not null, I set the state correctly. I think I may need to make this function `async`?

Answer (score 1):

You should return:

```
  return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'api/User/Login',
        data: { username, password },
    }).then(response => { ....
```

Take a look here: [is it considered good practice to pass callBacks to redux async action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138045/is-it-considered-good-practice-to-pass-callbacks-to-redux-async-action)

Although, I wonder what kind of thing you wish to do with that. When dealing with flux based patterns (such as Redux), we should keep the data flow in one direction (keep that in mind)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When the user login is successful, the code updates the redux state successfully. But, I also want to navigate user to the next page. That is why I wanted to do '.then()'. Does this make sense?

Comment: I guess it's opinionated. You can do this from within the action actually.

Comment: can you please clarify what do you mean by `from the action`? You mean from here `export const loginSuccess = (account) => ({
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload: { account }
})`

Comment: You use an async action creator (redux-thunk), so from within there you can navigate.

Answer (score 1):

you can change it like below:

```
export function Login(username, password) {
   return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loginBegin());
try{
      let res = await axios({
         headers:{
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
        'method': 'post',
        'url': 'api/User/Login',
        data: { username, password },
        });
     console.log('success: Login is successful');
     dispatch(loginSuccess(res));
  }
  catch(error)  { dispatch(loginFailure(error.response.data.message)) });

}
```

then you can use it like below:

```
cosnt FormSubmitHandle = async (values)=> {
    setFormSubmitted(true);

    let res = awiat props.login(values.username, values.password);
            console.log('YESSSS');
}
```